# How do I see for which post did I earn a hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

I just earned the SO Goes Flapper hat, but I am not sure which post caused me to earn it. Is there a way to check, or is that info hidden?

More generally, how can I check which post (if applicable) caused me to earn a particular hat, much like how I can see which post caused me to earn a badge.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320483/158100

Comment: They are not necessarily linked to posts, e.g. see:                                               **Team Player** - visit the Stack Overflow for Teams landing page at stackoverflow.com/teams

Comment: @TA That's why I said "(if applicable)"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to see this (this would also make some secret hats too obvious). You have to know [the exact trigger for this hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320483): an answer

- created by you
- during Winter Bash
- accepted
- with a score of at least 1

(and some other things we can't filter on). This leads to the following [search query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A5133585+created%3A2018-12-12..+isaccepted%3Ayes+score%3A1&mixed=0), with eleven results:

- [c# "Index was outside the bounds of the array" on empty Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53800128/c-sharp-index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the-array-on-empty-array/53800152?r=SearchResults&s=1|14.8269#53800152)
- [C# array of base class containing inherited classes, accessing non-inherited fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53756227/c-sharp-array-of-base-class-containing-inherited-classes-accessing-non-inherite/53756624?r=SearchResults&s=2|14.6862#53756624)
- [AssociatedType in a protocol with typealias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53738736/associatedtype-in-a-protocol-with-typealias/53738828?r=SearchResults&s=3|14.6543#53738828)
- [Convert String to DateTime with Leading Zero C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53756246/convert-string-to-datetime-with-leading-zero-c-sharp/53756446?r=SearchResults&s=4|14.5856#53756446)
- [why can't I initialise this set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53738608/why-cant-i-initialise-this-set/53738753?r=SearchResults&s=5|14.5824#53738753)
- [Swift closure giving function to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53775086/swift-closure-giving-function-to-variable/53775139?r=SearchResults&s=6|14.4797#53775139)
- [UIView alpha does not update after first call to change it. (Swift 4.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53825923/uiview-alpha-does-not-update-after-first-call-to-change-it-swift-4-2/53825965?r=SearchResults&s=7|14.4668#53825965)
- [Inconsistent accessibility: Base class is less accessible than parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53794392/inconsistent-accessibility-base-class-is-less-accessible-than-parent-class/53794423?r=SearchResults&s=8|14.3885#53794423)
- [In iOS tutorial, how to increase spacing on the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807620/in-ios-tutorial-how-to-increase-spacing-on-the-left/53807671?r=SearchResults&s=9|14.3722#53807671)
- [How typechecking works in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53824633/how-typechecking-works-in-swift/53824919?r=SearchResults&s=10|14.3254#53824919)
- [why if not satisfying this statment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53794323/why-if-not-satisfying-this-statment/53794444?r=SearchResults&s=11|14.2879#53794444)

The only one which is short enough and has a competing long answer is [the first one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53800152/4751173). According to [the explanation by balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320483) it should've been awarded earlier, but there was a bug in the system. Otherwise, it would be linked to the acceptance of your answer, which would provide another clue which post you earned it for.

Comment: Who’s balpha? Can you link to his explanation?

Comment: If you'd followed the first link, you had known :) But I've added a second link.